# What would be good starting encounters in a village to start a campaign?

Tags: gm-preparation

Following things are in the village area,
a forest, lots of farms, a tavern, in the forest is an old battlefield.

The PCs are green (lvl1,Novice, ...). The players like dark fantasy.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, idea generation questions like this are not a good fit for the site but we do have a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33707) where you can ask this sort of thing, including our own [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) (chat requires 20 rep). Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Hello Ludos and welcome to the site! Unfortunately this site is a Q&A service, where we specialize in questions with objective answers. For idea generation, you can join the [chat] once you've got 20 reputation or visit one of [these RPG forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) we maintain a list of. Welcome!

Comment: Even if this wasn't going to get closed instantly for being opinion-based, these kinds of things are also entirely dependent on setting and what kind of game system you are running.

Comment: You have enough reputation to enter the [chat] now :)